# Обойти несколько страниц ajax-ом в цикле

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.

Необходимо обойти несколько страниц `ajax`-ом в цикле. Проблема в том, что цикл завершается до отработки `ajax` (да, я знаю что асинхронный запрос по определению так и должен себя вести.). Есть массив с `ID` элементов и их нужно подставлять в `URI` при обходе `Ajax`'ом, т.е. запросы должны быть по разным `URI`, а в моём случае парсит данные только с последнего.

Может есть какие-то плагины, или всё же придётся делать запрос синхронным? В общем: подскажите как поступить, если сталкивались. Заранее спасибо!

UPD:

```
for (var i in settings.publics) {
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      cache: false,
      url: 'https://domain.com/method/id=' + settings.publics[i],

      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: А надо все запросы одновременно запустить или поочереди?

Comment: По очереди. Напрашивается ответ с синхронным запросом - но я не хочу, чтобы браузер подвисал при этом.

Comment: пример кода покажите. скорее всего синхронно не надо делать.

Comment: @eicto обновил вопрос.

Comment: А может все-так стоит дописать туда проверку ошибки?

  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert(textStatus);
      console.log(jqXHR);
      }

А то, ведь, причин может быть уйма. Нет по нужному адресу JSONp-а — и все.

Comment: и что не так работает ? console.log(data) должен правильно отрабатывать.

[вот как у вас](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QXdAB/8/), [вот как кошернее](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QXdAB/7/)

Comment: вероятно, у вас не получается вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QXdAB/9/

Comment: @eicto может и должен. но вот не работает.
В объекте хранятся ID, они циклом перебираются и по каждому парсится инфа. Соответственно - урлы разные. У вас в примерах они одинаковые

Comment: у меня разные запросы, url это или data - не важно. [вот вам пример с url](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/QXdAB/11/) - я правда в тонкостях jsonp не разбираюсь, поэтому ответ немного странно выглядит

Answer (score 1):

Ну, я вижу 2 варианта:

1. Ждать загрузки аякса (например с помощью флага): до запроса ставим `false`, внутри обработки меняем на `true`, а после ожидаем флага `true`
2. Вызывать следующую итерацию цикла после загрузки. Примерно как писал [@inso](/users/7892/inso)

Answer (score 0):

```
var make_generator = function(array) {
    var clone = array.slice(0);

    return function() {
        return clone.shift();
    };
};

var gen = make_generator(settings.publics);

var run = function() {
    var id = gen();

    if (typeof(id) == "undefined") {
        // last element
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: 'https://domain.com/method/id=' + id,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // some proccesing

            run();
        }
    });
};

run();
```

Comment: а где сказано что settings.publics это Array а не Object ? к тому-же вы реализовали практически синхронную загрузку, в то время, как может быть первый запрос выполняется 10 сек а второй  - 0.01

Comment: "Есть массив с ID элементов и их нужно подставлять в URI при обходе Ajax'ом"
Добавить поддержку объектов не сложно.
Запросы асинхронны, но выполняются по завершению очередного, как и требовалось в комментарии оставленном автором вопроса.